# How to call function from component from array of pushed objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of text components generated from the `.push()` function:

```
handleWordPress = (i) => {
 this.setState({selectedWord: this.props.navigation.state.params.meanings[i]});
};
render() {
 const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
 var words = [];
 var keys = Object.keys(params.meanings);
 for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  words.push(<Text style={{color: 'grey', padding: 10, fontSize: 20}} key={i} onPress={this.handleWordPress(i)}>{keys[i]} </Text>);
 }
 return (
  <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
    <Text>{words}</Text>
    <Br/>
    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Tap on a word to see the meaning</Text>
    <Br/>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 40, fontWeight: '800'}}>{this.state.selectedWord}</Text>
  </ScrollView>
 )
}
```

The problem is, if there are 3 items in the array, it always renders as `this.handleWordPress(4)` because of the `for` statement. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `let` instead of `var` in your `for` loop.
Like so:

```
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
   words.push(<Text style={{color: 'grey', padding: 10, fontSize: 20}} key={i} onPress={this.handleWordPress(i)}>{keys[i]} </Text>);
}
```

Here's an example to see the difference between `var` and `let`:

```js
var p$ = document.getElementById("p$");
var array = ["I", " am", " a", " boy"];


// Won't work whit var in first paragraph
// Takes only final i which will be the length of array
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var time = i * 500;
  setTimeout(() => p1.textContent += array[i], time);
}

// Will work whit let in second paragraph perfectly
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var time = i * 500;
  setTimeout(() => p2.textContent += array[i], time);
}
```

```html
<p id="p1" style="background: beige;">with var:  </p>
<p id="p2" style="background: #fee;">with let:  </p>
```

---

**EDIT:** *(answer to the comment)*
It works because:

A variable declared using `var` is not local to the `for` loop block, but is local to the enclosing function scope or global scope. So it is getting updated at each iteration of the loop. And when the timer comes to read the variable `i` in my example, it finds `i == array.length`.

`let` works differently. It is local to the enclosing block instead *(the `for` loop block in our case)*.
At each iteration, we will have a new instance of `i`, and all the instances have different values.

Find out more here: [let - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Scoping_rules_2)

Answer (score 1):

All of your words have a reference to the `i` variable, and as you have seen, at the end of a loop of length x, `i = x+1`. To overcome this, you could use `Array.prototype.map()` right in your render function as follows:

```
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          {words.map((word, i) => {
            return (
              <Text
                style={{ color: 'grey', padding: 10, fontSize: 20 }}
                key={i}
                onPress={this.handleWordPress(i)}
              >
                {keys[i]}
              </Text>
            );
          })}
        <Br />
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
          Tap on a word to see the meaning
        </Text>
        <Br />
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 40, fontWeight: '800' }}>
          {this.state.selectedWord}
        </Text>
      </ScrollView>
    );
```